# Spaces removed from tikzlibraries' code when loaded within \ProvidesExplPackage

Tags: expl3, package-writing, tikzlibrary

I'm playing with `expl3` in a project and have a weird issue.

I have a package that loads `tikz` and some `tikzlibraries`.
If I use `\ProvidesExplPackage`, it seems that spaces are removed somewhere in the `tikzlibraries`, leading to errors such as

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/arrowkeys/linecap/.ischoice' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. }
```

while the key should be `is choice`.

Here is a M(non)WE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{essai_expl3.sty}
  \RequirePackage{expl3}
  \ProvidesExplPackage{essai_expl3}{2022-04-01}{1.0}{essai expl3}
%  \ProvidesPackage{essai_expl3}[2022-04-01 v. 1.0 essai expl3] 
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{essai_expl3}

\begin{document}
  azerty
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Solution provided by @Ulrike Fischer does the job on the MWE.

I've similar issue with pgf…

```
\begin{filecontents}{essai_expl3.sty}
  \RequirePackage{expl3}
  \RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
  \ProvidesExplPackage{essai_expl3}{2022-04-01}{1.0}{essai expl3}
  
  \keys_define:nn { essai_expl3 }
  {
    % pour charger et pouvoir utiliser TikZ
    ,tikz .bool_gset:N      = \g_essai_tikz_bool
    ,tikz .default:n        = true % valeur par défaut
    ,tikz .initial:n        = false % valeur initiale
    ,tikz .value_required:n = false % si pas de valeur donnée, true est utilisée
    % pour les options non définies
    ,unknown .code:n = \ClassInfo{ Estia }{Option~ inconnue~ `\l_keys_key_str'}
  }
  
  \ProcessKeysOptions { essai_expl3 }
  

\bool_if:NTF \g_essai_tikz_bool
{
  \usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=true}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,use comma}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
}
  \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[tikz]{essai_expl3}

\begin{document}
  azerty
\end{document}
```

Comment: imho \usetikzlibraries doesn't use the provided methods to store and restore the expl3 catcodes (the libraries from tcolorbox do), so you should disable them manually with \ExplSyntaxOff and reenable them after the loading with \ExplSyntaxOn.

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Looks like an ansewr to me

Comment: @JosephWright I was just trying to figure out where we had that discussion, and it is much older than I thought ;-) https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/235

Comment: Trying the solution on the real case gives an other error (same type). See the edit. Let me know if I must open a new question.

Comment: @NBur you cannot do catcode changes in the argument of a command. You might try `\if_bool:N \g_essai_tikz_bool ... \fi:`

Comment: I solve the second issue replacing problematic spaces in `\…pgf…` commands by `\c_space_tl`.

Comment: use `~` (tilde) for spaces, e.g. `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show~suggested~version=true}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX provides commands to push and pop the catcodes. It is described here
https://www.texdev.net/2015/07/30/making-custom-loaders-expl3-aware/

It is for example used by `\usepackage`, so normally you don't have to worry if you load a package in a expl3 package.

But not all loader for libraries use these commands. One correct example is `\tcbuselibrary` from tcolorbox, it basically does

```
\def\tcb@load@library#1#2{%
     ....
    \@pushfilename%
    \xdef\@currname{#2}%
    ...
    \input\tcbpkgprefix#2\relax%
    ...
    \@popfilename%
  }%
}
```

tikz/pgf's library loader doesn't use it, so you should do it manually

```
 \@pushfilename
 \xdef\@currname{arrows.meta}%
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \@popfilename
```